# Do items despawn?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac

I just found a heart!  Unfortunately, I don't *need* this heart, but I am 100% sure I will need it later.  If I leave the heart alone long enough, will it disappear?  What about coins and other items?

[image]

Comment: I will point out that in that picture, you have no choice but to leave the hearts. You can't pick up hearts if you are at full health.

Comment: @murgatroid99 - I know that's why I asked :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, items on the ground never despawn as long as you are on the same floor (and once you leave it doesn't matter since you can never come back anyway).

Comment: As added note, you even see the items left behind on the minimap. Though, only one per room, I think.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty helpful